# Insert Data Into A Table Using The Same Foreign Key Value

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc, pypyodbc

I'm using SQL Server, Python, pypyodbc.
The tables I have are:

```
tbl_User: id, owner

tbl_UserPhone: id, number, user_id
```

user_id is the primary key of User and the foreign key of UserPhone.
I'm trying to insert 2 different phones to the same user_id using pypyodbc.
This is one of the things I tried that did not work:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
SQLCommand = ("INSERT INTO tbl_UserPhones"
                    "(id,number,user_id)"
                    " VALUES (?,?,?)")
values = [userphone_index, user_phone,"((SELECT id from tbl_User where id = %d))" % user_id_index]
cursor.execute(SQLCommand, values)
cursor.commit()
```

Comment: Can you please explain `did not work`? Did you get an error? Need more info

Comment: No, it just skipped the cursor.commit() line. does it supposed to work?

Comment: If I were you, I would use Python to print out the SQLCommand, then try pasting that command into a console for SQL Server (like Management Studio) to see what the error is. I would guess that it's how your tbl_UserPhones table is defined, but it's impossible to know without more information.

Comment: this is what I get: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'tbl_UserPhones' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Comment: I don't want to change it to ON because I don't want to change the index of user_id, just insert data to the same key.

Comment: If you don't want to insert with identity_insert turned on, then surely you want the db to generate the value for you. Please try your insert without specifying the id column and thus letting SQL Server generate the value for you. `INSERT INTO tbl_UserPhones (number, user_id)`

Comment: I succeeded inserting a row using the SQL Server console by doing: 
INSERT INTO tbl_UserPhones (id,number,user_id) VALUES 
 (1,'dfsd',(select id from tbl_User where id = 0));

But I still can't do it with Python.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify: (1) Is `[tbl_UserPhone].[id]` an IDENTITY column for that table, and if so, is it also the Primary Key? (2) Do you already know the `[tbl_User].[id]` value that you want to insert into the `[tbl_UserPhone].[user_id]` column?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, you have an identity column in `tbl_UserPhones`. Based on the column names I'm guessing it's the `ID` column.

The exception you get is very clear - you can't insert data into an identity column without specifically setting `identity_insert` to `on` before your insert statement. Basically, messing around with identity columns is bad practice. it's better to let Sql server to use it's built in capabilities and handle the insert to the identity column automatically.

You need to change your insert statement to not include the id column:

Instead of

```
SQLCommand = ("INSERT INTO tbl_UserPhones"
                "(id,number,user_id)"
                " VALUES (?,?,?)")
values = [userphone_index, user_phone,"((SELECT id from tbl_User where id = %d))" % user_id_index]
```

try this:

```
SQLCommand = ("INSERT INTO tbl_UserPhones"
                "(number,user_id)"
                " VALUES (?,?)")
values = [user_phone,"((SELECT id from tbl_User where id = %d))" % user_id_index]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SQLCommand = ("INSERT INTO tbl_UserPhones"
                "(id,number,user_id)"
                " VALUES (?,?,?)")
user_sqlCommand = cursor.execute("(SELECT id FROM tbl_User WHERE id = %d)" % user_index).fetchone()[0]
values = [userphone_index, user_phone, user_sqlCommand]
```

This was the solution.